# Prove that all order topologies are regular

Tags: general-topology

I've attempted a proof of this which I believe to be somewhat unique, as I have not seen something similar here or else where.

X is an order topology.

Given a point $x_0$ $\in$ $X$ and a closed set $A$ such that ($x_0 \lt a $) $ \forall a \in A$,   $\exists$ $N(x_0)$ such that $N(x_0) \cap A = \emptyset$

Define $B=X-N(x_0)$; $A \subseteq B$ as $\forall a \in A$, $a \not \in N(x_0)$.

Consider the case where $\exists a_0 \in A $ such that $(x_0,a_0) = \emptyset$

Construct $W = \cup(n,a_0)$ where $n \in N(x_0)$ and $V = \cup(x_0,b)$ where $b \in B$ and $x_0 \lt b$

By construction, $x_0 \in W$ and $A \in V$, where $V$ and $W$ are both open and $W \cap V = \emptyset$

Now, consider the case where $\exists d \in X$ such that ($x_0 \lt d \lt a$) $\forall a \in A$

$W = \cup(n,d)$ where $n \in N(x_0)$ and $V = \cup(d,b)$ where $b \in B$ and $x_0 \lt b$

By construction, $x_0 \in W$ and $A \in V$, where $V$ and $W$ are both open and $W \cap V = \emptyset$

In the case where $\exists a_1 \in A$ such that ($x \le a_1$) $\forall x \in X$
then $V = V \cup$  { $a_1$ } ; by construction, $V$ is now both closed and open, but this still satisfies the definition of regularity.

Similarly, if ($x_0 \le x$) $\forall x \in X$, then $W = W \cup$  { $x_0$ }, which is again a set that is both closed and open.

Repeat the construction of $V$ and $W$ in the case where ($a \lt x_0$) $\forall a \in A$ using the above method to complete the proof.

Does this proof work to prove regularity of an arbitrary order topology? the case where $x_0$ is the least element in the topology seems a bit sketchy in construction, and I don't know if the way I've done it is the most straight forward.

Thank you!

Comment: You should state upfront that $X$ has the order topology; otherwise your statement "$x_0 < a$" is completely meaningless.

Comment: @pyridoxal_trigeminus you're right, I was sloppy in the write up and just counted on the title implying it.

Comment: @AnotherUser That one is extremely similar, but in my opinion long and wordy when maybe it need not be. I'm hoping my use of the approach cuts down enough of the length without cutting away too much.